# Infopath : Check "Multiple Select Box" values from code behind

Tags: infopath, infopath2010, infopath-2007, infopath-forms-services

[image]

I have a Multiple Selection Box in infopath with four manual values.
Now how can I check two of the options from code behind C# (Say "Option One and Option Three").

At the moment if I am adding these two from code behind by saying,

```
XPathNavigator elemYourTextBox = this.MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("//my:MSList", this.NamespaceManager);
elemYourTextBox.SetValue("Option One");
elemYourTextBox.SetValue("Option Two");
```

only `Option Two` gets selected.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I have used InfoPath So I may be off the mark here. The reason, I believe, is you are setting one value twice. once as `Option One` then as `Option Two`.  You will need to replicate how infopath inserts the values into the text field to get the default values selected.  One thing to consider is that you may need a collection of values for this to work that way you want, as that is usually how Infopath works with multiple values.

Found this article that will help
[Pre-select items in a Multiple-Selection List Box in InfoPath 2010](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2010/pre-select-items-multiple-selection-list-box-infopath-2010.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your response,well i have got a solution by changing their XML properties.

Answer (score 0):

Multiselect list boxes are bound to a repeating node in InfoPath. So in your code, you'll need to add an MSList node, then set it's value. I believe you can just append the node to create a copy of it. Here is a rough code sample to show the concept - this relies on one instance of field1 (which my multiselect is bound to) being present in the form, but hopefully will at least get the main idea across.

```
        XPathNavigator option = this.MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:group1/my:field1", NamespaceManager);
        this.MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:group1", NamespaceManager).AppendChild(option);
        this.MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:group1/my:field1[1]", NamespaceManager).SetValue("Option 1");
        this.MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:group1/my:field1[2]", NamespaceManager).SetValue("Option 2");
```

Comment: i tried this but was getting null pointer exception in public void DeleteNil(XPathNavigator node)
        {
            if (node.MoveToAttribute("nil", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"))
                node.DeleteSelf();
        } this method

Comment: So, you are calling another method to delete the nil attribute and it is throwing an error? In your sample, you are setting a text box - a string field won't have the nil attribute.